# Selected/Clicked UIButton text title color need to change from number of buttons on scrollview programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

I added number of UIButtons on scrollview programmatically based on array count, until this much its working fine. Requirement is only selected button text title color should change into brown color remain are blue.  I can’t able to solve this one please some one help using Swift 3. I need only the selected or clicked button text title color need to change remain all are in rest of the color.

```
           for titles in arrayPageTitles {
        var titleSize: CGSize = (titles as AnyObject).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
        titleSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(ceilf(Float(titleSize.width))), height: CGFloat(ceilf(Float(titleSize.height))));

        /**
            creating top page strip tab Buttons
         */

        buttonTitle = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        buttonTitle = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonPositionX + 5, y: 10, width: titleSize.width+40, height: (scrollViewTop?.frame.size.height)! - 20))
        buttonTitle.setTitle(titles, for: .normal)
        buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .selected       

        buttonTitle.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonTitle.layer.masksToBounds = true
        buttonTitle.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        buttonTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1
        buttonTitle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor

        buttonTitle.tag = increaseIndex
        buttonTitle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTitleAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        arrayTitleButtons .add(buttonTitle)
        scrollViewTop?.addSubview(buttonTitle)
        let currentButtonX:CGFloat = buttonPositionX
        let buttonWidth:CGFloat = buttonTitle.frame.size.width
        buttonPositionX = currentButtonX + buttonWidth + 10

        if arrayPageTitles.first == titles  {

            viewLine.frame = CGRect(x: buttonTitle.frame.origin.x, y: buttonTitle.frame.origin.y, width: buttonTitle.frame.size.width, height: buttonTitle.frame.size.height)

            viewLine.layer.cornerRadius = 17
            viewLine.clipsToBounds = true
            viewLine.layer.masksToBounds = true

            viewLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            scrollViewTop?.addSubview(viewLine)
            scrollViewTop?.addSubview(buttonTitle) // need to fix ... this add only first button
            buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        }

        /**
            creating collection views
         */
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let pageStripTypeViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "kPageStripVC") as! FirstViewController
```

....

Comment: Show the code that you have used to add buttons in scrollView

Comment: Actually I need to integrate Page strip modal. Every thing is working fine except the selected button case

Comment: If you want help then you need to show us what you are currently trying

Comment: buttonTitle = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
            buttonTitle = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: buttonPositionX + 5, y: 10, width: titleSize.width+40, height: (scrollViewTop?.frame.size.height)! - 20))
            buttonTitle.setTitle(titles, for: .normal)
            buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
            buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .highlighted)
            buttonTitle.tag = increaseIndex

            scrollViewTop?.addSubview(buttonTitle)

Comment: Don't add code in comment, its hard to read code from comment, edit your question and add code in it

Comment: @NiravD can you send your mail id I will give the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the selection state of the sender in your @IBAction, as follows:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // create an array of buttons
    var mybuttonArray: [UIButton] = view.subviews.filter{$0 is UIButton} as! [UIButton]
    // filter it down to buttons that aren't the sender
    mybuttonArray = mybuttonArray.filter{$0 != sender}

    // figure out of it's selected
    mybuttonArray.forEach({ button in
        if button.isSelected {
            // unselected it
            button.isSelected = false
        }
    })

    // select the sender's button
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    // whatever else you need to
}
```

Comment: I tried this selection method, but its not working accurate. First I select Button3 and Button3 title text color is changed, but when I select Button5 then the both Button3 and Button5 title text color is same.

Comment: Can I give entire code, everything is working fine Page strip except this, please help me

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, all you're doing is changing the title text's color based on control states. You're doing that already in your setup code, so all you need to do is keep track of which buttons are selected.

Comment: OK I will try once

Comment: Hi thanks its working... the problem is in buttonTitle.setTitleColor(UIColor.brown, for: .selected) I changed into button.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.brown and now its working what I need thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the reference of the button when you create a selector so that you can compare with other buttons and change the isSelected state

`buttonTitle.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonTitleAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)` //replace ViewController with your ViewController name

```
func buttonTitleAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
      arrayTitleButtons.forEach { (button) in
           if button == sender {
               button.isSelected = true
               sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.brown, for: .selected)
           } else {
                button.isSelected = false
           }
        }
  }
```

Comment: which part is not working?  try putting break point and check the if condition is working or not?

Comment: it say arrayTitleButtons is empty and it exit the forEach condition. Its in last satge only this issues are there can you help me. I can send the code can you give mail id

Comment: why arrayTitleButtons is empty, you are adding buttonTitle to arrayTitleButtons right, try adding this line arrayTitleButtons.append(button Title) before line scrollViewTop?.addSubview(buttonTitle)

Comment: its working now I changed into buttontitle.titlelabel.textColor